# Using Correl Function in Excel for Varying Array Sizes

Tags: excel, excel-formula, pearson-correlation, vba

So the current setup of the problem at hand is that I have 4 columns, **Employee ID**, **Category 1**, **Category 2**, and **Category 3**. I need to find the correlation between Category 1 & Category 2, Category 1 & Category 3, and Category 2 & Category 3 for each Employee ID. The issue is that the array length for each Employee ID is different. Some employees will have 5 records, some employees will have 8 records to their ID.
This problem would be simple if the Subtotal button had the CORREL function built into it given its grouping by feature.

How would I go about calculating the 3 correlation coefficients for each unique Employee ID? Excel function or VBA works

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use an [array formula](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Guidelines-and-examples-of-array-formulas-7D94A64E-3FF3-4686-9372-ECFD5CAA57C7).  Please see this screen shot of a sample situation:

[image]

As you can see the formula for cell G2 is: =CORREL(IF($A$2:$A$16=F2,$B$2:$B$16,""), IF($A$2:$A$16=F2,$C$2:$C$16,""))  That is saying if cell in column A matches your employeeId, include the cell in corresponding column in the array (Column B for the first IF and Column C for the second ID).  After entering in the formula you need to make sure you hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to tell excel you want to do an array formula or <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> on a Mac.

You obviously need to modify the formula to fit the size of your data and you can copy that formula to any cells if you setup your $s correctly.

Comment: Thanks Zgirod and Kesh Shan! Worked beautifully